# Split a binary file into 4-byte sequences (python)

Tags: python, file-io

So, basically, I have a 256MB file which contains "int32" numbers written as 4-byte sequences, and I have to sort them into another file.

The thing I struggle with the most is how I read the file into an array of 4-byte sequences. First I thought this method is slow because it reads elements one by one:

```
for i in range(numsPerFile):
    buffer = currFile.read(4)
    arr.append(buffer)
```

Then I made this:

```
buffer = currFile.read()
arr4 = []
for i in range(numsPerFile):
    arr4.append(bytes(buffer[i*4 : i*4+4]))
```

And it wasn't any better when I measured the time (both read 128000 numbers in ~0.8 sec on my pc). So, is there a faster method to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read and write tasks are often the slow part of an activity.

I have done some tests and removed the reading from file activity from the timings.

- Test0 was repeating the test you did to calibrate it for my old slow
  machine.
- Test1 uses list comprehension to build the list of four byte chunks
  the same as test0
- Test2 builds a list of integers. As you mentioned the data was
  `int32` I've turned the four byte chunks in to integers to be used in Python.
- Test3 uses the array library to unpack the bytes as `int32` as suggested by the original poster. Used `frombytes` rather than `fromfile` to keep it consistent with the other tests.

Test3 was the fastest by some margin, followed by test2, test1, and test0 was always the slowest on my machine.

I only created 128MB file for test but it should give you an idea.

This is the code I used for my testing:

```py
import array
import time
from pathlib import Path
import secrets
import struct

tmp_txt = Path('/tmp/test.txt')


def gen_test():
    data = secrets.token_bytes(128_000_000)
    tmp_txt.write_bytes(data)
    print(f"Generated {len(data):,} bytes")


def test0(data):
    arr4 = []
    for i in range(int(len(data)/4)):
        arr4.append(bytes(data[i*4:i*4+4]))
    return arr4


def test1(data):
    return [data[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(data), 4)]


def test2(data):
    return [_[0] for _ in struct.iter_unpack('>i', data)]


def test3(data):
    arr4 = array.array('i')
    arr4.frombytes(data)
    arr4.byteswap()
    return arr4


def run_test():
    raw_data = tmp_txt.read_bytes()
    all_test = [
        test0,
        test1,
        test2,
        test3,
    ]
    for idx, test in enumerate(all_test):
        print(f"test{idx}")
        n0 = time.perf_counter()
        x0 = test(raw_data)
        n1 = time.perf_counter()
        print(f"\tTest{idx} took {n1 - n0:.2f}")
        if isinstance(x0, array.array):
            print(f"\tdata[{x0.buffer_info()[1]:,}] = [{x0[0]}, ..., {x0[-1]}]")
        else:
            print(f"\tdata[{len(x0):,}] = [{x0[0]}, ..., {x0[-1]}]")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    gen_test()
    run_test()
```

This gave me the following transcript:

```bash
Generated 128,000,000 bytes
test0
    Test0 took 10.50
    data[32,000,000] = [b'\x9f\x1cOO', ..., b'\x94\x8e\xd2?']
test1
    Test1 took 4.40
    data[32,000,000] = [b'\x9f\x1cOO', ..., b'\x94\x8e\xd2?']
test2
    Test2 took 3.31
    data[32,000,000] = [-1625534641, ..., -1802579393]
test3
    Test3 took 0.41
    data[32,000,000] = [-1625534641, ..., -1802579393]
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I also found some other options like `array.fromfile`, which happens to work even faster than `struct` methods, so I think that's also worth pointing out.

Comment: Updated answer to include using `array`. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
def bindata():
  array = []
  count = 0
  with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    while count < 64:
      f.seek(count)
      array.append(f.read(8))
      count = count + 8
  print(array)
    
bindata()
```

file.txt data: FFFFFFFFAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCDDDDDDDDAAAAAAAAEEEEEEEEFFFFFFFF

Answer (score 0):

I think I must have misunderstood your question. I can create a test file hopefully similar to yours like this:

```
import numpy as np
# Make 256MB array
a = np.random.randint(0,1000,int(256*1024*1024/4, dtype=np.uint32)

# Write to disk
a.tofile('BigBoy.bin')
```

And now time how long it takes to read it from disk

```
%timeit b = np.fromfile('BigBoy.bin', dtype=np.uint32)
```

That gives 33 milliseconds.

```
33.2 ms ± 336 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# Check all the same
print(np.all(a==b))
True
```

---

Or, if for some reason, you don't like Numpy, you can use a `struct`:

```
d = open('BigBoy.bin', 'rb').read()
fmt = f'{len(d)//4}I'
data = struct.unpack(fmt, d)
```